# How to send a json array with different json objects in a http request

Tags: arrays, json, object, go

I want to send this data "id":"ab1" , "name":"Mash" in a http request in Go.

example : `--data-urlencode 'data=[{"id":"ab1"},{"name":"Mash"}]'`

How can I send this in golang . I have string values to send id and name as seperate json objects in an array like [{"id":"ab1"},{"name":"Mash"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]interface{}` to represent the data to be encoded to the JSON array. An `interface{}` can hold any Go value.

```
data := []interface{}{t1{ID: "123456"}, t2{Name: "Slash"}}
p, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The types `t1` and `t2` in the snippet above are assumed to be the your types. Modify the names to your actual types.

Create a form:

```
form := url.Values{"data": []string{string(p)}}
```

Post the form:

```
http.DefaultClient.PostForm(url, form)
```